# Laravel Eloquent is adding double quotes around data insert

Tags: mysql, laravel

When creating a new record, I am trying to fill in a field which is LONGTEXT. I use it to store json data.

```
$newRecord = new Profile([
    'info' => '[]',
]);
$newRecord->save();
```

In the database, the data is being stored as "[]" (with quotes around the data entered) instead of [] which is breaking logic in my application. How can I make sure it enters the data correctly? Also, I have tried setting [] as default value for the LONGTEXT column but MySQL returns an error saying it's not allowed for LONGTEXT columns.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. 'info' column in this case is casted as an array in the Profile Model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'info' => 'array',
];
```

Using an empty array [] rather than '[]' as a String fixed the issue:

```
$newRecord = new Profile([
    'info' => [],
]);
```